# Silverlight: Encoding a webClient stream

Tags: windows, silverlight, windows-phone-7, encoding, webclient

I've been trying to get this to work, but I'm very frustrated at this point. I am a beginner in this field, so maybe I'm just making mistakes.

What I need to do is to take in a website .html and store it into a txt file. Now the problem is that this website is in Russian (encoding windows-1251) and Silverlight only supports 3 encodings. So in order to bypass that limitation, I got my hands on an encoding class that transfers the stream into a byte array and then tries to pull the correctly encoded string from the text. The problem with this is that

1) I try to ensure that webClient recieves a Unicode encoded stream, because the other ones do not seem to create a retrievable string, but it still doesn't seem to work.

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        wc.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode;
        wc.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(wc_LoadCompleted);
        wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(site));
```

2) I fear that when I store the html into a txt file using streamWriter, the encoding is, yet again, somehow screwed up.
3) The encoding class is not doing its job.

```
Encoding rus = Encoding.GetEncoding(1251);
        Encoding eng = Encoding.Unicode;
        byte[] bytes = rus.GetBytes(string);
        textBlock1.Text = eng.GetString(bytes);
```

Can anyone offer any help on this matter? This huge detriment to my project. Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to handle an encoding alien to Silverlight you should start with downloading using `OpenReadAsync` and `OpenReadCompleted`.

Now you should be able to take the `Stream` provided by the event args `Result` property and supply it directly to the encoding component you have acquired to generate the correct string result.

Comment: Thank you! I've re-written I changed to the 'OpenReadAsync' but I still couldn't get the right text. Then I noticed that StreamReader has an encoding property, too, so I set that to Unicode, ran the code and it works!